# ipython and fork()

Tags: python, fork, process, ipython

I am planning a Python script that'll use `os.fork()` to create a bunch of child processes to perform some computations. The parent process will block until the children terminate.

The twist is that I need to be able to run the script both from the Unix shell using `python` and from `ipython` using `%run`.

In what manner should the child processes terminate to avoid breaking back into the `ipython` command prompt? In my experience, `sys.exit()` won't do.

Comment: Would it be easier to use subprocess, rather than os.fork?

Comment: I don't get your last paragraph. What you want to do after child process terminates OR what's wrong sys.exit()?

Comment: @Thomas K: Good suggestion, but the solution I am contemplating is critically reliant on `os.fork()` for RAM usage and performance reasons.

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan: I want the child process to terminate as opposed to breaking back into the `ipython` shell. Try it if you're not sure what I'm talking about.

Comment: damn i'm on Mac and don't have a windows (: Is this reported as a bug on iPython? does it always drop into shell even if you execute it outside command line prompt (maybe double-clicking to `.py` file)?

Comment: @ahmet alp balkan: This is neither a bug in `ipython` nor does it have anything to do with Windows.

Comment: damn I thought that it is ironpython. My bad, sorry.

Comment: What happens if the child processes just reach the end of their scripts without calling sys.exit()?

Comment: @Russell Borogove: They break back into the `ipython` prompt, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
import os, sys

child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
  print 'in child'
  os._exit(os.EX_OK)
  print 'hm... wasn''t supposed to get here'
else:
  print 'in parent'
```

The trick is to use [`os._exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit) instead of [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit). The documentation contains the following passage:

> **Note** The standard way to exit is
>   `sys.exit(n)`. `_exit()` should normally
>   only be used in the child process
>   after a fork().

Answer (score 0):

In Linux terminology, instead of `fork`ing the iPython process, why don't you `exec` a regular python interpreter from the iPython shell and have that one fork?

Comment: I have massive in-memory data structures which I need to access from both the interactive `ipython` shell and the script (both parent and child processes). Hence the use of `fork` from `ipython` down.

Comment: How about using shared memory? I've never tried POSH (Python Object Sharing), but I've heard wonders about it. You could then structure your processes any way you liked.